# Possibility of Java to work in Yii2

Tags: java, php, yii2

I have a simple question, is it possible to develop something in Java for the website which has been developed in Yii2 framework? I know that Yii2 is php framework this is why I've raised this question. If it is possible, then please let me know the pros and cons of that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the website that is developed is written in PHP. A different language, a different syntax.

It is possible to use a Java library, but to completely write the website from PHP Yii2 to Java with Yii2 is rewriting and partly rebuilding everything and probably not using the Yii2 framework anymore.

But using a Java Library, for example generating documents, is possible.
For example: The JasperReports Library is written in Java and compatible with the Yii2 framework. See the link for more instructions how to include it. -> [GitHub chrmorandi / yii2-jasper](https://github.com/chrmorandi/yii2-jasper)